# How to stop a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've been learning about Threads, yeha... I'm a noobie. I have one problem, i don't know how to stop a Thread because the method .spot() was deprecated. I want to know how to safely stop a thread. I did this:

```
public class Principal{

    private boolean bo1;
    private Thread tr1;


    public Principal(){

        bo1 = true;
        tr1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(bo1){
                    //What the Thread does goes here, its a chronometer.
                }          
            }
        };  // The thread body stops here.
    }   // The constructor body stops here. 

    public void changeBo1(){
        if(bo1 == true){
            bo1 = false;
        }

        else{
            bo1 = true;
        }    
    } //Change bo1 ends here.
} //Class ends here.
```

So i'm making a mini-game for myself, and I the body of the method is a chronometer that shows me how long i'm taking to solve the puzzle. The deal is, when I start a new game, i call the method that resets the value of the seconds, minutes and hours and the changeBo1() 
so the clock stops. Then when I make the first click in the screen, the clock begins.Then, when I change the game. But the thread is not reading the change of value of the boolean, it restarts to 0:00:00 and, without me clicking the screen, keeps going to 0:00:01--- 
(This doesn´t happen with the first game, since the variables are the ones needed, it happens when i click "new games", when the variables need to change).

How do I need to allow the thread to read the change of the boolean bo1?

Comment: read [this](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#shuttr) :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make bo1 [volatile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable):

```
private volatile boolean bo1;
```

This is because, sometimes, one thread can read a stale value after another thread has changed that value.  The simple explanation for this is each thread has its own copy of memory that both threads share, and sometimes that private copy can be out of sync.

**bo1** is what's commonly referred to as a sentinel variable.  Just a fancy way of saying the variable controls a loop.

Remember, the two threads aren't synchronized, so they could be in any state.  You must carefully control that state.  Just because you set `bo1` to false doesn't mean the thread using that as a **sentinel variable** is actually finished executing, as it may not have processed this change and exited the loop yet.

You'll need to [join threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to ensure execution completion.  If Thread1 calls `join`  on Thread2, Thread1 will be blocked until Thread2 is finished executing.  (A thread calling `join` on itself will not be blocked.)

Here's a rewrite, using the techniques mentioned above.

```
public class Principal{

private boolean bo1;
private Thread tr1;


public Principal(){

    bo1 = true;
    tr1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(bo1){
                //What the Thread does goes here, its a chronometer.
            }          
        }
    };  // The thread body stops here.
}   // The constructor body stops here. 
public void stopThread(){
    changeBo1();
    tr1.join();
}
public void changeBo1(){
        bo1 = !bo1;
} //Change bo1 ends here.
} //Class ends here.
```

If you are ever in a situation where you need to loop to process data (such as parsing a streaming protocol, or just processing some list of items) it may be useful to follow a pattern like so:

```
public class ProcessRunnable implements Runnable{
    private final Queue<Item> queue = new LinkedList<Item>();
    public void run(){
        while(active){
            synchronized(queue){
                while(queue.size()>0){
                    Item item = queue.remove();
                    //process item
                }
                queue.wait();
            }
        }
    }
    public void add(Item item){
        synchronized(queue){
            this.queue.add(item);
            this.queue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This brings up the [notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll%28%29) and [wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) functions.  Calling `Wait` on an object will block a thread until another thread calls `notify` or `notifyAll` on the same object.  This can be used to indicate data is available, or more generally, some notable event has occurred.  This is necessary because not waiting will cause a thread to run as fast as possible, consuming much CPU.

Comment: Edited to discuss wait and notify.

Answer (score 6):

First, add the `volatile` keyword to `bo1`:

```
private volatile boolean bo1;
```

The [volatile keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) guarantees that when any thread writes to the variable, any subsequent reads *from any other thread* will read the updated value. The lack of the keyword may cause some undesirable optimizations, based on the assumption the variable is only used on a per thread basis.

Also your function `changeBo1()` can be simplified to:

```
public void changeBo1() {
    bo1 = !bo1;
}
```

EDIT 1: Another way to do this is instead do this:

```
tr1.interrupt();
```

Which does two things for you:

1. If an operation inside `tr1` calls `Object.wait();`, the interrupt flag will release the block on the thread, so it can be shutdown.
2. You would no longer need a boolean to track when the thread should interrupt; you can use the following snippet inside `run()`:

   ```
   while(!isInterrupted()){
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: I've explained why in my answer, and also added several other suggestions.

Comment: +1..but ,It would be better,If you add some more description,for better understanding :)

Comment: mmm, volatile keyword has so little impact on performance I'd not even mention it personally.  Volatile is obviously necessary here.

Comment: @AlexGittemeier nice answer +1, but you have forgot about the interrupt message :D

Answer (score 2):

For stopping a thread first you need a Conditional variable. In your case 
it is

```
private boolean bo1; // should declare it volatile
```

second very important point you need to interrupt the corresponding thread 
which you want to stop. Because it may be the case that your thread is 
waiting (wait()) and will not check the condition variable and hence will not stop.

i.e you need to call

```
tr1.interrupt(); // interrupts the  thread and brings out of wait state
```

**Always remember a thread only dies/stop when its complete is run method normally/or through some exception.**

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

As others answered the `bo1` should be modified with `volatile` keyword. And those accessing block might be modified with `synchronized` keyword.

```java
class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (stop) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // do your job
        }
    }

    public synchronized void setStop() {
        stop = true;
    }

    private volatile stop = false;
}
```

**Approach 2**

There is a handy method for thread interruption. Check [Thread#isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) out.

```java
class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        while (!isInterrupted()) {
            // do your job
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Thread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(10000L);
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't suggest the approach 1, but the second approach is better, while it's better to use a flag instead of interrupted flag

Comment: @William Morrison I don't like extending `Thread`, neither. It's just an example per OP's code.