# Stopping public void run() Android

Tags: android

i need to stop the run() thread after 30sec or anytime i clicked on a button. My question is how can i stop  public void run().

```
   @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              int currentPosition= 0;
                int total = mp.getDuration();
                while (mp!=null && currentPosition<total) {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        currentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        return;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return;
                    }        

                    sbMusicProgress.setProgress(currentPosition);

                    /*MP3 PROGRESS*/
                    timer_count++;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {


                            if (timer_count<10)
                                context.txMp3Prog.setText("00:0"+String.valueOf(timer_count));
                            //Stop playlist after 30seconds

                            else if (timer_count==30){
                                timer_count=0;
                                context.txMp3Prog.setText("00:00");
                                mp.pause();
                                sbMusicProgress.setProgress(0);
                                btPlayMp3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.air_deezer_play);                        
                            }

                            else
                                context.txMp3Prog.setText("00:"+String.valueOf(timer_count));

                            }

                        });


                }
        }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481315

Comment: have you tried to interrupt the thread(thread.interrupt())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `interrupt` on your thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

`public void interrupt ()`

Posts an interrupt request to this Thread. The behavior depends on the state of this Thread:

1. Threads blocked in one of Object's wait() methods or one of Thread's join() or sleep() methods will be woken up, their interrupt status will be cleared, and they receive an InterruptedException.
2. Threads blocked in an I/O operation of an InterruptibleChannel will have their interrupt status set and receive an ClosedByInterruptException. Also, the channel will be closed.
3. Threads blocked in a Selector will have their interrupt status set and return immediately. They don't receive an exception in this case.

I would suggest you to use a `Handler`.

```
 int count =30;
 Handler m_handler;
 Runnable m_handlerTask ;
 m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
 {
     @Override 
     public void run() { 
   if(count>=0)
   {     
         // do something 
     count--;    
   }
   else
   {
    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask); // cancel the run                     
   } 
  m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);    
  }
  };
  m_handlerTask.run();
```

`public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)`

Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are in the message queue.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that I wanted to mentioned is `stop()` method of thread is deprecated.

```
So what is the good practice to stop a thread?
```

Ans. is you have to complete the life-cycle of thread by completing `run()` method of of particular **Thread**.

In your case try to complete the `run()` method by `setting one flag variable` after 30 sec or on click of button.

And second solution which mentioned by @Raghunandan.

Try [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) which is oracle doc they had explain about **thread interrupts**.